# Accessing numpy array elements by key

Tags: python, numpy, indexing

Is there an easy way to access array elements by (string) key as well as by index?
Suppose I have an array like this:

```
x = array([[0, 4, 9, 1],
           [1, 3, 9, 1],
           [3, 5, 6, 2],
           [6, 2, 7, 5]])
```

I am looking for way to specify a set of keys (for example `('A', 'C', 'G', 'T')`) that can be used as an alias for an index.
So `x['A', 'C']`, `x[0,'C']`, `x['A', 1]`, and `x[0,1]` all return the value 4;
`x['G', :]` is the same as `x[2, :]`, and so on.
I know that this can be achieved by subclassing a numpy array and overriding `__getitem__` and `__setitem__`, but subclassing gets complicated very quickly, so I was wondering if there is a simpler or better way to do this.

Comment: Is the array always (4m4) with the same 4 keys?  What numpy math are you doing?  Any fancy indexing, or just this basic element access?

Comment: Simplest is to define a map/dictionary, `dd = {'A':0, 'C':1, ...}` and index with x[dd['A'],:]`.  I'd look at the `numpy.lib.index_tricks.py` file to see classes that define their own indexing.

Comment: @hpaulj Different instances of the same array class may have different keys. However, the keys of any instance of the array class won't change during its lifetime. I expect that basic element access is sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a pandas DataFrame:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

x = np.array([[0, 4, 9, 1],
              [1, 3, 9, 1],
              [3, 5, 6, 2],
              [6, 2, 7, 5]])
df = pd.DataFrame(x)


df.columns = df.index = ['A', 'C', 'G', 'T']

df

   A  C  G  T
A  0  4  9  1
C  1  3  9  1
G  3  5  6  2
T  6  2  7  5

df.loc['A', 'C'] # loc for location
4
```

or

```
df.iloc[0,1] # iloc for index location
4
```

However you cannot access elements using mixed syntax, namely `df.loc[0, 'C']`,  `df.iloc[0, 'C']`, `df.loc['A',1]` and `df.iloc['A', 1]` will all raise an error.

Comment: ```df.iloc[1,2]``` will do exactly what you've missed;)

Comment: Yes I forgot to add that, I meant that you cannot use mixed syntax as in the example. I will edit to clarify that.

Comment: Thank you. The thing is though that this is intended for an open-source software project, and we prefer to avoid adding a new dependency if there is a simple way of achieving the same behavior just with numpy.

Comment: @Michiel Pandas is a very well documented and mantained library, I see no drawbacks in using it for any opensource project. I looked for an other workaround, but I ended up with no proper solution to this problem